# How to remove an element from std::vector if the element id matches a search parameter

Tags: c++, vector, smart-pointers

I'm trying to write an algorithm which will search for, and remove an item from a vector of items, if the item ID matches an argument. See example code below:

```
struct item{
    item(int newID){id = newID;}
    bool operator==(const item& other){return id = other.id;}
    int id
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<item>> vec;

vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<item>(new item(10));
vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<item>(new item(15));
vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<item>(new item(20));
```

so, using the above code, I want to be able to search for the item which stores the value 15, and remove it from the vector, deleting it.

How would I go about doing this?

Admittedly, I probably need to brush up on the use of unique pointers too, so please feel free to correct me if my syntax is incorrect.

Some of the solutions I have attempted are as follows:

```
void remove_item(int id){
    vec.erase(
               std::remove_if(
                               vec.begin(),
                               vec.end(),
                               [](const item& e){
                                     return id==e.id;
                               }),
               vec.end()
              );
```

The above code produces an error stating that the variable id is not part of the capture list for lambda expression.

Secondly, I've tried:

```
void remove_item(item e){
    auto iter = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), e);
    vec.erase(iter);
}
```

The above code in this case produces type mismatch errors in the == operator member function.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  There is a ton of information out there on this

Comment: Yes, I've tried using remove_if lambda expressions, which causes the compiler to complain about the search parameter not being part of the capture list. I've also tried using a std find expression with a predicate function, and a == operator on the item class. None of which works

Comment: You should show that then so we can help you with it.  Just asking how you could do it is too broad as there are loots of ways to do this.

Comment: Show us your lambda! And remember that `remove` and `remove_if` don't actually remove anything. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Comment: I'll update the question to show some of my attempted solutions

Comment: Btw. your example code doesn't compile. You have several missing ")" and ";".

Comment: Sorry about that, I was typing freehand as I was trying to simplify the code as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `id` to the capture list of the lambda so it has access to it.  Then you need to make the type passed to the lambda the type of `*vec.begin()` which is a `std::unique_ptr<item>` and not an `item`

```
void remove_item(int id){
    vec.erase(
               std::remove_if(
                               vec.begin(),
                               vec.end(),
                               [id](const std::unique_ptr<item>& e){
                                     return id==e->id;
                               }),
               vec.end()
              );
}
```

Removing all of the other extraneous error from you code you would have something like:

```
struct item {
    item(int newID) { id = newID; }
    bool operator==(const item& other) { return id == other.id; } // == here not =                                          
    int id;
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<item>> vec;

void remove_item(int id) {
    vec.erase(std::remove_if(
        vec.begin(), vec.end(), [id](const std::unique_ptr<item>& e) 
                                    {   return id == e->id; })
        ,vec.end());
}

int main()
{
    vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<item>(new item(10))); // was missing a close paren
    vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<item>(new item(15))); // was missing a close paren
    vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<item>(new item(20))); // was missing a close paren
    remove_item(15);
    for (const auto & e : vec)
        std::cout << e->id << " ";
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fde1a384772a1a15)</kbd>

Comment: ...and even then the code doesn't work, because you have `id==e.id;` instead of `id==e->id;`.

Comment: the overloading of "==" wasnt required here i guess

Answer (score 2):

Use remove-erase idiom:

```
// search for this value
const int val = 15;

// use lambda capture to get "val" into lambda
auto lambda = [val] (const std::unique_ptr<item> & a) { return a->id == val;};

// use remove-erase idiom
auto rem = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), lambda);
vec.erase(rem, vec.end());
```

Comment: This code removes the pointer from the vector. But will the memory it points to be also freed?

Answer (score 0):

As said by Fred Larson, you should use the "erase remove_if" idiom.
For example :

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<item>> vec;
vec.push_back(std::make_unique<item>(10));
vec.push_back(std::make_unique<item>(15));
vec.push_back(std::make_unique<item>(20));
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
  [](std::unique_ptr<item> const& item) -> bool { return item->id > 10; }), vec.end());
std::cout << vec.size(); // Output will be 1
```

Comment: the problem with this, is that I need to be able to search and remove items  not based on a hard coded value (in your example, 10)

Comment: You can use the lambda capture to do so. ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to state that instead of using `push_back` & `insert`, prefer `emplace_back` & `emplace` for `C++ containers`. I m saying this because instead of writing like this :-

```
vector<unique_ptr<item>> v;
v.push_back(unique_ptr<item>(new item(5));
```

You can simply do this :-

```
vector<unique_ptr<item>> v;
v.emplace_back(new item(5));
```

Secondly as you need to know whether you want to remove "one item" or "all items" of the value 15. It's because for the former one you need to use `find_if` whereas for the second case you should use `remove_if`. You can use `remove_if` in the first case too (but not `find_if` in second case) however it isn't recommended as `remove_if` does shifting of the elements which isn't required in the first case. Plus `find_if` simply returns the iterator to the item where the condition first matches. Hence choice is yours & use it judiciously.

The codes are as follows :-

```
// find_if
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct item
{
    int x;
    item(){}
    item(int x)
    {
        this->x=x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<item>> v;
    v.emplace_back(new item(15));
    v.emplace_back(new item(5));
    v.emplace_back(new item(7));
    v.emplace_back(new item(15));
    v.emplace_back(new item(27));
    v.emplace_back(new item(15));
    v.emplace_back(new item(80));

    cout<<"deleting the item storing value 15...\n";
    auto itr = find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](unique_ptr<item> &u)     // you cant copy two `unique_ptr` as they can always be `moved & not copied`, hence we are `passing them by reference`
    {
        return (u->x==15);
    });
    v.erase(itr);    // as you need to remove only one item so specify the `iterator` pointing to the required item in `erase`

    for (auto &u:v)  see the use of `reference` again as without it the compiler throws error messages
    {
        cout<<u->x<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be :-

```
deleting the item storing value 15...
5 7 15 27 15 80
```

For `remove_if` you just need the following modifications :-

```
auto itr = remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](unique_ptr<item> &u)
    {
        return (u->x==15);
    });
    v.erase(itr,v.end());    // as you need to delete a range of items so you need to specify a range (here `itr` to `v.end()`) in `erase`
```

The output here will be :-

```
deleting the items storing value 15...
5 7 27 80
```

Now I guess your doubts would be cleared well properly !!!